# To isolate 2 PCbs...or not

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have a SBC (single board computer) that feeds power and i2s signals to a DAC.

The problem is that SBC generates a lot of noise and I am thinking to add a "[DC to DC isolated converter](http://eu.mouser.com/Power/DC-DC-Converters/Isolated-DC-DC-Converters/_/N-brwkv?P=1z0wbp7Z1yx5k7uZ1z0x0e6&Ns=Pricing%7C0)" + LDO and use some galvanic isolator on the i2c lines.

My question is: will this help substantially as far as removing noise from DAC analog output  ?

Comment: Personally I'd go with a star ground and shielding.

Comment: I think this will greatly improve. Almost all industrial applications have ADC/DAC isolated from CPU so it makes sense to go in that direction.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I've used products that go this route e.g. EMU-1212m, which has separate analog and digital boards, and has good performance (lives up to -120dB noise claim). There's no DC-DC isolation on the analog board of that product.

Comment: And to Johan: first you need to quantify what you hope to achieve in terms of noise reduction (what do you measure now and what you want). Keep in mind that nowadays on-motherboard <$2 DACs (Realtek ALC889) can deliver -108dB noise with no fancy supply circuitry involved, just a basic LM7805 (recommended on p. 71 of [the datasheet](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/datasheets/ALC889_DataSheet_1.0.pdf)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, "maybe".

On the one hand, you may well get rid of much of your SBC noise (or maybe not, unless you learn about control of ground currents, noise filtering, etc), but you will then have to contend with switching noise from your DC-DC converter. In general, the more compact the converter, for a given power capability, the less filtering it incorporates and the more you have to worry doing the filtering yourself.

If you're still having trouble, be aware that you can use high-speed optocouplers for most i2s systems as long as the setup is strictly SBC master/DAC slave, and in principle almost completely eliminate noise from the SBC, although you'll then have to worry about radiated noise, conducted noise, ground coupling, etc.

Comment: The author said DC/DC converter + LDO. Digital lines from converter and analog trough LDO supplied from dc/dc converter, I suppose.

Comment: I am planing to add the DC-DC isolated converter + LDO on power and digital isolator in i2s lines.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič - Oh yes, I picked up on that. My point is that this is not any guarantee that he will eliminate all noise.

Comment: You can never "eliminate all noise". He needs to quantify what problem he is having and what his goal is before asking here several vague "what if" questions...